# global variable not printing correctly in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am playing around with some recursion, and trying to count the number of additions in a recursive fib function (code below). The problem is, `g_add` never gets printed as anything but zero (0). In the debugger it is set correctly, but it wont print correctly. In fact, the code below is modified a bit, to sanity check that everything else is OK. In real life, g_add is set to zero initially, not to the 10 below, but look at the output is printing...

```
volatile int g_add = 10;
int rfib(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)  return 0;
    else if(n == 1) return 1;
    else {
        ++g_add;
        return rfib(n-1) + rfib(n-2);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    printf("Fib: %d\n", g_add);
    for(int n =0; n<6;n++,g_add = 0)
    {
        printf("Fib %d is: %d - additions: %d\n", n, rfib(n), g_add);
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Fib: 10
Fib 0 is: 0 - additions: 10
Fib 1 is: 1 - additions: 0 
Fib 2 is: 1 - additions: 0
Fib 3 is: 2 - additions: 0 (note, the debugger says it is 1)
Fib 4 is: 3 - additions: 0
Fib 5 is: 5 - additions: 0
```

Any thoughts on why g_add is not being printed correctly? And what I could do about it? I have tried with and without the volatile keyword. I think this might be related to the VS environment, rather than C++ so, I tagged both.

Comment: Function operands evaluation order is not specified by the standards i.e it is left to the compiler to decide the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming the order in which the parameters are evaluated.

Use this instead:

```
int fib = rfib(n);
printf("Fib %d is: %d - additions: %d\n", n, fib, g_add);
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was posting.  +1

Comment: Parameters are evaluated right to left unless you declare the function using the `__stdcall` calling convention, as far as I know.

Comment: @ Eduardo León: The order is not specified in the standard (delibrately). Thus compiers are free to evaluate them in any order. __stdcall on the other hand affects the ABI and just specifies what order they are pushed onto the stack, it has no affect on the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Order of evaluation of parameters to a function is not specified in the standard.
This compilers are allowed to do appropraite optimisations.

See:
[What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-c-programmer-should-know-about/367663#367663)

In your situation.

- It is evaluating the fourth argument (g_add)
- Before the third argument (rfib(n))